# android Gallery with arbitrary aspect ratios

Tags: android, image, gallery

i wish to have an android gallery that will host images of varying aspect ratios. what i'd like is something like CENTER_CROP for the images in the gallery. however, when i set the image scale type to this, the images overrun the gallery image border.

of course, FIT_XY results in squished / flattened images. CENTER results in horizontal or vertical black space inside the gallery image border.

any ideas how to accomplish this? every example i can find uses FIT_XY with fixed size images. i suppose i could crop the images myself but i'd rather not.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView;
    if (iv == null) {
        iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(galleryItemBackground);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
    }

    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = getInputStream(position);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // TODO?
        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
    }
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);



    /*
     * if (bitmaps[position] != null) { bitmaps[position].recycle();
     * bitmaps[position] = null; } bitmaps[position] = bm;
     */

    return iv;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just trimming the bitmap to a square myself, as,

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

// make it square

int w = bm.getWidth();
int h = bm.getHeight();
if (w > h) {
    // trim width
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, (w - h) / 2, 0, h, h);
} else {
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, (h - w) / 2, w, w);
}
```

Comment: This solution was not valid for me as I needed to entire image to be able to scroll it in the container ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and looking at ScaleType documentation I found it could be done using ScaleType.MATRIX, for example:

```
    int w = 1000;
    int h = 1000;

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, w, h, Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas g = new Canvas(bmp);     
    g.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, w, h), p);

    ImageView i3 = new ImageView(context);
    i3.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    i3.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    int viewWidth = 300;
    int viewHeight = 300;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(bmp.getWidth() / viewWidth, bmp.getHeight() / viewHeight, bmp.getWidth() / 2, bmp.getHeight() / 2);
    i3.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight);
    lp2.leftMargin = 100;
    lp2.topMargin = 400;
    lp2.gravity = 0;

    this.addView(i3, lp2);
```

This solution complicates things a little bit too much though. If you want to scroll and zoom the ImageView you need to use matrix scaling as well. So I'd be interested in knowing any possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of tasks I use this simple class. It fits height or width scaling the image properly (it depends on which is the smaller dimension) . After this operation it centers the image in the ImageView bounds.

```
public class FixedCenterCrop extends ImageView {


    public FixedCenterCrop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public FixedCenterCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public FixedCenterCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        recomputeImgMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        recomputeImgMatrix();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    private void recomputeImgMatrix() {
        final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

        float scale;
        final int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        final int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        final int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        } else {
            scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
        }

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        matrix.postTranslate((viewWidth - drawableWidth * scale) / 2, (viewHeight - drawableHeight*scale)/2);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```